# Python Thumbnail Issue

Tags: python

I am wanting to resize an image (size of image will vary at initial), I wanted to use `.thumbnail()` because it will resize the image without distorting the image. However I am getting this message and cannot seem to figure out what I am doing incorrectly.

[image]

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image

img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pic2.jpg", 1)
resized = img.thumbnail((360,360), Image.ANTIALIAS)

cv2.imshow("Grad", resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

`thumbnail` is a method of the `Image` class, not of a numpy array returned by cv2.imread.
Try creating an Image object, then to apply `.thumbnail()` on it.

Comment: As in convert the numpy array to an image object?